# What makes wrinkle-free cotton, wrinkle-free?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, polymers

*Disclaimer:*

No, I don't own any "wrinkle-free" articles of clothing. So I haven't been able to observe first-hand if "wrinkle-free" clothing *is* totally "wrinkle- free" (if it isn't, then perhaps "wrinkle-resistant" might be an appropriate term?).

---

Back to question:

**At the molecular level, what is it that makes cotton "wrinkle-free"? What chemo-physical process(es) is cotton subjected to, here?**

I ran a cursory Google-search, and [this was the best article that I could find](http://www.businessinsider.in/How-a-brilliant-female-chemist-who-owns-55-patents-re-invented-cotton-and-made-it-the-fabric-of-our-lives/articleshow/48993164.cms), albeit, it's sorely lacking in information on the *actual* processes involved in the production of "wrinkle-free" cotton.

Comment: Don't have time to read this, but I believe this is the patent for it: https://www.google.com/patents/US6123739

Comment: A short overview is provided on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent_press , too. And http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/004051756103100408 (DOI: 10.1177/004051756103100408) one of the first articles about it.